# Medical test for travel to Canada

Tags: visa, canada, medical

I am an Indian citizen. I have a valid Canadian Student visa valid from April 2016 to March 2018. I am planning to travel to Canada in early 2017. The validity of my medical test performed for the issuance of the said visa is till December 2016 (as it was done in December 2015).

Will I be able to travel to Canada in early 2017 without having to undergo the medical test again? Can I do the medical test after I arrive in Canada in case I am required to?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/medical/medexams-temp.asp) page you might have to. Quoting: `Your medical exam results are valid for 12 months only. If you do not come to Canada as a visitor, student or worker within that time, you may need to have another exam.`

Comment: @Dipen I have checked that page but it says "you MAY need to have another exam". So it is not a confirmed statement.

Comment: Exactly. They don't know for sure. You may. You may not. That's what it means.

Comment: In case I travel to Canada without the test, will I be allowed to enter? Do you have any idea may be?

Comment: Nobody knows. When they say you might nobody knows. It's best to take it again when you don't know for sure

Comment: This is so weird! They have issued a visa for 2 years but the medical test is valid for 1 year!!

Comment: The medical test is always valid for 1 year regardless of the duration of the visa. Your medical conditions might change into 1 year so its always fixed to 1 year. Nothing weird about that.

Comment: So as per your suggestion, it's better and safer to have the medical test again before I go.

Answer (score 1):

According the [Canada Immigration and Citizenship](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/medical/medexams-temp.asp), the medical exam which Canada requires, whether it be for visiting, residency, or employment, must be valid when you present yourself at the border for entry.

The exam results are valid for 12 months from when they were issued and, if you don't enter Canada as a visitor, student or worker within that time, you may need to have another exam.

As you note that you plan to enter more than a year from the time your medical exam was conducted, you may want to check in advance with the Consulate that issued your visa.